# Restricting mouse and keyboard in autoit?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, autoit

I'm trying to create a script so that during a task my keyboard/mouse is restricted from use aswell as whilst waiting for something what doesn't have a trigger/way of detecting if it's done I need it to stop me or anyone from moving the mouse/typing for at least 40 seconds.

Would this be possible to do in autoit and if so does anyone know how I can acheive this?

thanks GTPE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for `BlockInput()` which allows you to block keyboard and mouse from doing anything, the overriding command is: CTRL + ALT + DELETE

Basically just put `BlockInput(1)` at the start which will stop all keyboard/mouse from functioning

Then at the end put `BlockInput(0)` which releases control and allows you to do what you want.

#### 60 Second BlockInput

```
BlockInput(1)
    $timer = 60
    For $i = 1 To $timer Step +1
        Sleep(1000)
        $Coords = MouseGetPos()
        ConsoleWrite($timer - $i & " seconds Remaining" & @CRLF)
        TrayTip("Keyboard & Mouse Frozen", $timer - $i & " seconds Remaining", 1)
        ToolTip($timer - $i & " seconds Remaining", $Coords[0], $Coords[1], "Keyboard & Mouse Frozen")
    Next
BlockInput(0)
```

I added notifications using `ConsoleWrite`, `TrayTip` and `ToolTip` just so that it doesn't freeze and confuse you.

Psst: This bit of code is fantastic for when you want to clean a keyboard without unplugging it or turning the computer off :P

Comment: Anyday, let me know if you need something more advanced than that :)

Comment: You could also block CTRL + ALT + DELETE using an external dll.